# buffering issue with java communicating vlc

Tags: java, sockets, vlc, rtsp

I'm a newbie to Socket communication, so I may be wrong, but please advice or at least give the direction!

I'm implementing an RTSP server according to http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html#appendix taking a look to the similar code from http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/mynpr/com/webeclubbin/mynpr/RTSPserver.java.htm

At the moment I'm implementing responce to the OPTIONS request. To make it easy in the first approach, I decided to hardcode the answer according to the sample RTSP request/response log done for some real communication between vlc and gstreamer rtsp.

So, the log recorded with vlc URL -vvv says:

```
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://localhost:8554/test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.8 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.04.30)


Received 183 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, GET_PARAMETER, PAUSE, PLAY, SETUP, SET_PARAMETER, TEARDOWN
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 19:56:53 GMT


Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://localhost:8554/test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.8 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.04.30)
Accept: application/sdp
```

i.e.

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, GET_PARAMETER, PAUSE, PLAY, SETUP, SET_PARAMETER, TEARDOWN
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 19:56:53 GMT
```

part is 183 bytes length

I'm writing to the buffer right according to the example:

```
 try{
        System.out.println("S -> C");
        System.out.println("RTSP/1.0 200 OK");
        System.out.println("CSeq: "+RTSPSeqNb);
        //System.out.println("Session: "+RTSP_ID);
        if (responceType==OPTIONS) {System.out.println("Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, GET_PARAMETER, PAUSE, PLAY, SETUP, SET_PARAMETER, TEARDOWN");};
        if (responceType==OPTIONS) {System.out.println("Server: GStreamer RTSP server");                                                        };
        if (responceType==OPTIONS) {System.out.println("Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 19:56:53 GMT");};
        RTSPBufferedWriter.write("RTSP/1.0 200 OK"+CRLF);
        RTSPBufferedWriter.write("CSeq: "+RTSPSeqNb+CRLF);
        //RTSPBufferedWriter.write("Session: "+RTSP_ID+CRLF);
        if (responceType==OPTIONS) {RTSPBufferedWriter.write("Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, GET_PARAMETER, PAUSE, PLAY, SETUP, SET_PARAMETER, TEARDOWN"+CRLF);};
        if (responceType==OPTIONS) {RTSPBufferedWriter.write("Server: GStreamer RTSP server"+CRLF);                                                        };
        if (responceType==OPTIONS) {RTSPBufferedWriter.write("Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 19:56:53 GMT"+CRLF);            };
        RTSPBufferedWriter.write("Session: "+RTSP_ID+"\r"+CRLF);
        RTSPBufferedWriter.flush();

        //RTSPBufferedWriter.newLine();
        System.out.println("RTSP Server - Sent response to Client.");

    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught: "+ex.getStackTrace());
        //    System.exit(0);
    }
```

and the vlc log says

```
Opening connection to 127.0.0.1, port 6666...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://127.0.0.1:6666/autostream.mjpg RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.8 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.04.30)


Received 193 new bytes of response data.
[0x7fd01c001178] live555 demux debug: connection timeout
[0x7fd01c001178] live555 demux error: Failed to connect with rtsp://127.0.0.1:6666/autostream.mjpg
```

Where CRLF is '\n'. Before I tried CRLF="\r\n"  (and no +"\r"+ in the last line) with

```
Received 198 new bytes of response data.
```

So, what is wrong there? What vlc is waiting for? Why default delimeters from the example doesn't work for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like I always find the answer to my questions after I publish them to stackoverflow...

DOUBLE CRLF should stand after the last header for the usual RTSP protocol 9not the customized one used in the example).